# spring-security-oauth2 client need to authenticated(relogin) again after get authorization code

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2

### Description

I have a authorization Server and Client Server.
The authorization Server works well, I tested it with postman to get accessToken and authorized code.
But the Client Server doesn't work.
In the authorization_code mode, client login, then get authorized code from  authorization Server successfully, the next step, browser should redirect to the redirect_uri, but it didn't, it redirected to client's login page.

### Info

java8, spring-boot-starter-parent-1.4.5.RELEASE, spring-boot-starter-security, spring-security-oauth2

### problem location

org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails, AccessTokenRequest)

```
   Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
        if (!resource.isClientOnly()) {
            throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                    "Authentication is required to obtain an access token (anonymous not allowed)");
        }
    }
```

The Authentication from SecurityContextHolder is AnonymousAuthenticationToken, and I don't know why.

### client Server config

```
 @SpringBootApplication 
 @EnableOAuth2Client 
 public class App {
       ............. 
 }

 @Configuration
 public class CustomWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");


        super.addViewControllers(registry);
    }

 }


 @Configuration
 public class CustomWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userService);

        super.configure(auth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/img/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/getCurrentUserInfo").authenticated()//the resource that need access token
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
         .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
    }
  ............. 



        @Autowired
        private OAuth2ClientContext clientContext;


        @RequestMapping("/getCurrentUserInfo")
        @ResponseBody
        public Map<String, String> getCurrentUserInfo(){

            AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails resourceDetails = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
            resourceDetails.setClientId("authorization_code");
            resourceDetails.setClientSecret("123456");
            resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token");
            resourceDetails.setUserAuthorizationUri("http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize");
            resourceDetails.setScope(Arrays.asList("empty"));               OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate =  new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails, clientContext);

            Map<String, String> result = restTemplate.getForObject(URI.create("http://localhost:8082/user/getCurrentUserInfo"), HashMap.class);

            logger.debug("------------------------- result: {}",result);

            return result;
        }


    @Service
    public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

        private static List<String> grantTypes = Arrays.asList("authorization_code", "password", "client_credentials", "implicit");

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

            if(!grantTypes.contains(username)){
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("用户 %s 不存在!", username));
            }

            User user = new User(username, "123456", Arrays.asList());

            return user;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am so stupid, it's a Cookie(session) problem.
My Authorization Server and Client Server have same domain: localhost, but different port. Authorization Server is 8080, Client Server is 8081.
Client Server login first, has cookie.
Authorization need to login before to approve the Authorization.
When Authorization login,Client's cookie is covered.
When browser redirect to Client's page, Client can't find itself's session with Authorization's cookie.